# What happens to Aluminium in Autoclaved Aerated Concrete

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, redox

Aluminium is used in Autoclaved Aerated Concrete in order to produce the holes.

On Wikipedia I'm reading about the ingredients: sand, calcined gypsum, lime (mineral), cement, water and Aluminum powder.

Also it says "Aluminum powder reacts with calcium hydroxide and water to form hydrogen".

I'm wondering what Aluminium ends up as if anyone can help with detailed reactions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\ce{2Al + 7Ca(OH)2 -> Ca[Al(OH)4]2 + 3H2 ^ + 6CaO}$$ 
or maybe 
$$\ce{2Al + Ca(OH)2 + 6H2O -> Ca[Al(OH)4]2 + 3H2 ^}.$$
I think you'd get basically (ha) aluminium hydroxide.  This is effective because bases can dissolve the protective aluminium oxide layer that usually protects aluminium metal from corrosion.  The concrete is foamed by the hydrogen.